# Is it Bottling Time?

Tags: secondary-fermentation

My bitter has been fermenting for 9 days now and I think it's time to bottle? Temp is fine and gravity is 1.006 for 3 days running,just in the bottling mark. No activity now, just a small amount of froth for the last 3 days.[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. It's at a stable gravity that's a reasonable terminal gravity for that style (1.006 is a *little* dry for a bitter, but just a little). The krausen has fallen back into the beer, which is why there's just "a little froth" and "a small head". It's bottling time.

Comment: Gonna wack this in me barell asap 

Comment: Barrel? I thought this was about bottling.

Answer (score 0):

not as experienced as other HBs (2 brews completed, 1 fermenting), but sounds likes its ready to bottle.

Personally I would bottle it.

following the directions for adding priming sugar....etc...etc

Comment: Says should be ok after 4-6 days. It's my first brew so I hope it doesn't explode . Gonna go ahead and barrel it I think.  Has yours ever had a small head near bottling? ?

Comment: yes, so far both had no real head at bottling, one left in primary for 2.5 weeks (stout), second was racked to secondary for 2 weeks (red ale). Mine looked very similar to your picture.... having a head at bottling should not matter, from what i can tell.

Comment: Coming out of primary fermentation, beer has something like 0.8-0.9 volumes of CO₂ dissolved. This is enough for a very small "head"; carbonation ranges from maybe just-below-2.0 for english bitters, to the low-/mid-2.0's for most styles to 3.0 for highly-carbonated styles.